# flash a ST board with STLINK and Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, raspberry-pi, stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I am trying to flash a board of ST (STM32 discovery Kit STM32L072) via the STLINK connector, from a Linux, in command line.

To flash with the STLINK, you just have to copy-past the binary to flash into the USB reader (associated to the STLINK);

For that, with *dmesg*, I find the */dev/sdx*.
Then I mount the */dev/sdx*:

```
mkdir /mnt/board
sudo mount /dev/sdx /mnt/board
```

With a *ls* command I can read the folder of the ST board:

```
$ ls /mnt/board/
DETAILS.TXT  MBED.HTM
```

==> I can read the ST board.

Now I can copy the binary to the ST board. The flash should be automatically done after the copy:

```
sudo cp mybinarytoflash.bin /mnt/board
```

We can see the LED of the STLINK blinks, in green. The binary is flashing.

But I have 2 mains problems:

- Sometimes, after the copy of the binary into the */mnt/board*, the flash of the binary to the ST board is not been immediatly. Sometimes we have to wait more of 30 seconds.
- My second problem, it's that after the flashing, there is not RESET of the ST board. When I do this process with a computer with Windows, the ST board is reseted after the flashing. Do I need to do something with the */dev/sdx* or something else?

thank you very much,
Guillaume

Comment: Maybe you have to use the command `sync` to tell Linux to immediately write all files to the drives instead of keeping them in internal buffers.

Comment: it is not a programming question.

Comment: Hi P__J__. Maybe it's not a pure programming question, but maybe my way to copy the binary to the the USB driver (STLINK) is not perfect, and there is a method to do a better copy. With Windows it works very well. With Linux and my method it doesn't work perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

I find a new solution using a tool to drive the STLINK as a probe:

install the STLINK tools with:
`sudo apt-get install stlink-tools`

- **FLASH** : `sudo st-flash write <file_to_flash>.bin 0x08000000`
- **RESET** : `sudo st-flash reset`

This solution works perfectly and the flashing is quick.

Comment: Useful answer. How does `st-flash` knows which `/dev/sdx` (USB device connected to STM32 board) to use? I don't want to flash my hard drive (that holds the OS of the PC...) :(

Comment: Also why `0x08000000`? Is this board dependent?